# Converting params to a POJO to query H2 database

Tags: java, spring

Currently implementing a url based query spring controller and take an example query

```
  search/?driverId=1&driverId=2.
```

The controller looks like the following:

```
  public List<DriverDTO> searchDrivers(@RequestParam Map<String, 
   String> params) {}
```

My main concern, is how to map the Map params to a POJO like below, so that i can use that map to query the H2 database. Or is it possible to query directly to the database?

```
  public class queryDO {

   private Long id;

   private ManufacturerType manufacturerType;

   private int rating;

  }
```

This is my first time doing this type of query api so any examples (can't find any at the moment on github).

Answer (score 1):

Th following should work just fine if your `QueryDO` class has getters and setters:

```java
public class QueryDO {
    private Long id;
    private ManufacturerType manufacturerType;
    private int rating;
    // getters / setters
}

@RestController
public class SearchController {
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public List<DriverDTO> searchDrivers(QueryDO query) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If parameter name from query strings matches the property of the `QueryDO` class, Spring will map automatically it into the corresponding property of the `query` object.

For example query:

```
search/?id=1&rating=35
```